# Codeigniter instance losing connection to database inside of threaded closure

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following code is called in a controller that is invoked from php-cli using `php index.php [controllername] [methodname]`.

This code is also nested inside a `foreach` loop. The code ultimately calls a model which queries the database with the built-in mysql driver. The issue here is  that the first iteration, Codeigniter is  able to successfully connect to the database from a model call. However...

On the second iteration the model is loaded and the method is called when driver returns a null result from a database query. `$ci_instance` variable is a copy of $this inside the context of the controller.

I have also had similar issues with trying to mock models in Codeigniter PHP unit testing.

```
  $thread = ThreadManager::async(function () use (
        $ci_instance,
        $model,
        $function_name,
        $vars,
        $log_id,
        $cron
    ) {

        $exception = NULL;

        try
        {
            $ci_instance->load->model($model);

            $success = $ci_instance->$model->$function_name($vars);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $exception = $e->getMessage();
        }

        if($success)
        {
            $ci_instance->cron_queue_model->close_crontab($cron['id']);

            $ci_instance->cron_log_model->update_note($log_id, 'info', 'Completed #'. $cron['id']. '-'. $model.'/'.$function_name . ' ' . $success);
        }
        else
        {
            $ci_instance->cron_log_model->insert_error($cron['id'], 'error', 'Failed -'. $model.'/'.$function_name . ' ' . $exception);

            log_message('error', 'The model:' . $model . ' function:' . $function_name . ' with vars:' . $vars . ' did not run as expected ' . $exception);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Joseph. Your last edit seemed to right-indent the code, the purpose for which I didn't understand - but this removed a number of readability edits I made (I've reinstated my edits). It's worth refreshing your browser before editing to help avoid this, and if you see a warning during your edit, it is often best to cancel, refresh and try again, so as not to overwrite the latest version.

Comment: Sorry @helfer I dont write a lot of questions so still getting used to how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have somewhat resolved this issue. When I did this I got the following response:

```
mysql_stat($ci_instance->db->conn_id);
```

"MySQL server has gone away"

So I added the following line in the try catch block and it works:

```
try
{
    if(mysql_stat($ci_instance->db->conn_id) === "MySQL server has gone away")
    {
        $ci_instance->db->reconnect();
    }

    $ci_instance->load->model($model);

    $success = $ci_instance->$model->$function_name($vars);
}
```

I still cant however get this working in its own process without waiting for a result from the process control fork.

Comment: where can we add this query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the codeignigter API at all, but I have ran into a similar problem in my own work. My specific issue was that the database connection was being closed in my class' __destruct method. What I suspect is happing is when your closure returns (what I assume means the thread dies) PHP is calling the destructor on your DB instance and perhaps closing the connection. Since the DB connection is shared this closes the connection for all this instances of the class.